# C programming debug child process

Tags: linux, multiprocessing

I want to debug a child process using gdb after this:

```
execl("./child","./child",NULL);
```

so I attached the pid of it but how can put a break point in the child process to start from a specific place.

Comment: Why not just start the child process with gdb?

Comment: @DavideBerra: perhaps because before the `fork` some weird `pipe`-s have been established...

Comment: Because it takes the pid of its parent and connect to the shared memory